# nsfetchedresultscontroller with 1-* and *-*

Tags: ios, core-data

Maybe this is pushing NSFetchedResultsController too far... anyway, this is what I'm trying to do:

I have the core data classes and relationships: `A <->> B <<->> C` (A has 1 to many to B, B has many-to-many to C). I'm given one object of type A. I want to use NSFetchedResultsController to give me all reached objects of type C (NOT distinctly - I want duplicates), where the sectionNameKeyPath is the 'name' property of the B object. Possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that is possible with a `NSFetchedResultsController`. A FRC can
only display the result of a fetch request, and a fetch request returns 
objects of a given entity *without duplicates*.